# Operador in no java

Tags: java, operadores

Estou aprendendo Java e me deparei com a necessidade do operador `in`. Por exemplo:

Eu tenho um vetor (`v = {1,2,3,4,6}`) e eu quero ver se se o 5 está neste vetor (não tem neste caso).

No python seria `v = [1,2,3,4,6]` - `6 in v`, aí ele retornava `False`. Eu quero fazer isso no Java, mas não ache o operador que funciona.

Como faço isso em java?

Comment: Precisa varrer com um loop cada indice.

Answer (score 6):

Utilizando java-8, é possível verificar através da API [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4};
boolean contains = IntStream.of(a).anyMatch(x -> x == 5);
```

Veja um teste no [ideone](https://ideone.com/w2561X)

Sem utilizar streams, também é possível dessa forma:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int[] number = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    if(contains(number, 5)){
        System.out.println("Contem o numero 5");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Nao contem o numero 5");
    }
}

public static boolean contains(final int[] array, final int v) {

    boolean result = false;

    for(int i : array){
        if(i == v){
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Também funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/7TIj3e).

---

## Referências:

- [Java – Check if Array contains a certain value?](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-check-if-array-contains-a-certain-value/)
- [How can I test if an array contains a certain value?(SOEn)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1128728/5524514)

Answer (score 6):

Esse operador que você procura é o método [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-). A finalidade dele é exatamente essa que você quer.

Se você trocar o seu array por um `Set` ou `List` e a solução é simples. Para isso, você pode usar o método [`asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) para transformar o seu array em lista:

```
List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 6);
System.out.println(lista.contains(5)); // false
System.out.println(lista.contains(4)); // true
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/8Iz36p)

Comment: Acho que vale ressaltar que não funciona com primitivos.

Comment: @Articuno Se você usar `int[] v = ...;` e `Arrays.asList(v);`, não vai dar certo mesmo. Mas se você usar o `asList` como varargs, aí funciona. E com isso você aproveita de minimizar o uso dos horrorosos arrays.

Comment: Muito interessante, não sabia desse detalhe.

Comment: Com o ellipsis vai funcionar porque ele faz o autoboxing? Eu acredito que funciona, mas o mecanismo que faz isso funcionar me é estranho

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim. O compilador determina que o método `Arrays.asList(Object...)` é o que se encaixa. Então ele transforma isso em `Arrays.asList(new Object[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 6})`. Para converter os números em objetos, ele faz o autoboxing, e o resultado é `Arrays.asList(new Object[] {Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2), Integer.valueOf(3), Integer.valueOf(4), Integer.valueOf(6)})`. Esse exemplo permite a nós aprecisar a beleza do varargs e do autoboxing trabalhando juntos para abstrair essa complexidade toda em fazer algo tão simples.